# How do I get part of a compound index following a where clause?

Tags: indexeddb, dexie

I have my stores defined like so :

`db.version(DB_VERSION).stores({
  STATE: 'state',
  LOGS: '[timestamp+activity]',
})`

This creates a [compound index](https://dexie.org/docs/Compound-Index), which is accessed later on like this:

```
await db.LOGS.where('[timestamp+activity]')
    .below(Date.now() - 604800000)
    .delete()
```

However the above snippet gets the **compound**, whereas I only need to pull out **timestamp** to run the `below` method on. The idea here is to delete indexed items older than a week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are querying the compound index, the argument must be an array of first and second value.

Just change it to:

```js
await db.LOGS.where('[timestamp+activity]')
    .below([Date.now() - 604800000, -Infinity])
    .delete();
```